# Case for x200 Expansion Board & Raspberry Pi

Tags: case

There are plenty of cases around for just the Raspberry Pi but I bought the x200 expansion board and now I cannot find a case that will protect the two components while attached to each other.

Is there a case that will cover the `Raspberry Pi B+ connected to the x200 expansion board`? I don't have a 3D printer but I work with a guy who does so if you could at least point me to some blueprints for printing a case for these two components as a whole that'd be great.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you will find an off the shelf case that fits both. However, you may be able to modify this [case](https://www.modmypi.com/shop/modmypi-model-b-plus-raspberry-pi-case-black) made by modmypi to fit, assuming you get the right number of spacer plates (the spacer plates were specifically designed to accommodate expansion boards). You could also go the DIY route and build a [Lego case](https://www.google.com/search?q=raspberry%20pi%20lego&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=947&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=Rwq7VOCWO-TjsATw-4LYDw&ved=0CD4QsAQ). I would also suggest that you may get better results asking this of the creators/sellers of the expansion board.